# Webpack. Как исправить Chunk.entry was removed. Use hasRuntime()?

Tags: webpack

Пишет в консоль:

> /home/projects/Game/node_modules/webpack/lib/Chunk.js:59 throw new
>   Error("Chunk.entry was removed. Use hasRuntime()"); ^
>
> Error: Chunk.entry was removed. Use hasRuntime() at Chunk.get entry
>   [as entry]
>   (/home/projects/Game/node_modules/webpack/lib/Chunk.js:59:9) at
>   /home/projects/Game/node_modules/extract-text-webpack-plugin/index.js:201:13
>   at Array.filter (native) at Compilation.
>   (/home/projects/Game/node_modules/extract-text-webpack-plugin/index.js:200:37)
>   at Compilation.applyPlugins0
>   (/home/projects/Game/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:68:14) at
>   Compilation.seal
>   (/home/projects/Game/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:558:8) at
>   /home/projects/Game/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:474:16 at
>   /home/projects/Game/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:225:11 at
>   _addModuleChain (/home/projects/Game/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:472:11)
>   at processModuleDependencies.err
>   (/home/projects/Game/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:443:13)
>   at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:67:7) at
>   process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)

**webpack.config.js:**

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");

const extractCSS = new ExtractTextPlugin('./public/stylesheets/[name].css');
const extractLESS = new ExtractTextPlugin('./public/stylesheets/[name].less');

module.exports = {

    context: path.join(__dirname, 'frontend'),
    entry: {

        style: 'stylesheets/style.less',
        babelPolyfill: "babel-polyfill",
        ReactIgnore: "./ReactIgnore",
        App: "./App",
        index: "./index.js",
        initialState: "./initialState.js",
    },
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
        filename: '[path][name].[ext]',
        publicPath: '/public/',
        library: '[name]'
    },
    resolve: {
        modules: [path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules")]
    },
    resolveLoader: {
         modules: ["web_loaders", "web_modules", "node_loaders", "node_modules"],
    },

    module: {
      rules: [
        {
            exclude: /\/node_modules/,
            loader: "babel-loader",
            options: {
                presets: [['es2015', {modules: false}], "es2016", "es2017", "react"],
                plugins: ['transform-runtime'], 
            },
        },
        {
            test: /\.less$/,
            use: extractLESS.extract(["css-loader", "less-loader"]

        },
        {
            test: /\.css$/,
            use: extractCSS.extract(["css-loader"]),

        },
        {
            test: /\.(png|jpg|svg|ttf|eot|woff|woff2)$/,
            use: "file?name=[path][name].[ext]",
        }
      ]
    },
    plugins: [

        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: "jquery",
            jQuery: "jquery",
            "window.jQuery": "jquery",

        }),

        new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin(),
        extractLESS,
        extractCSS,

    ],
    watch: true,
}
```

Пробовал разные варианты, пришел к вводу, что дело в **ExtractTextPlugin**.
Без него все собирается без ошибок.

```
use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract(
                {
                    fallback: "style-loader",
                    use: ["css-loader","autoprefixer-loader?browsers=last 2 versions","less-loader"],
                    publicPath: "./public/stylesheets",
                }),
            },
        {
            test: /\.css$/,
            use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract(
                {
                    fallback: "style-loader",
                    use: ["css-loader","autoprefixer-loader?browsers=last 2 versions"],
                    publicPath: "./public/stylesheets",
                }),
        },
```

И разные варианты.
Как решить данную проблему?

Comment: Вы обновили вебпак на второй и у вас сломался плагин под первый вебпак. Обновите плагин тоже

Comment: Сырые хипстерские инструменты такие сырые и хипстерские) Вот ишью на гитхабе, https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/2764 , недавно опять сломали и пофиксили, ставить надо rc3 extract-text-плагина (npm install --save-dev extract-text-webpack-plugin@^2.0.0-rc.3)

Comment: Именно поэтому я пока стремаюсь переводить рабочий проект на второй вебпак

Comment: @Утка Учится Уму то есть лучше пока что использовать первый?

Comment: Во втором есть ряд потенциально вкусных фич вроде тришейкинга, но всякие плагины и лоадеры и конфиги для старых версий могут странно ломаться. Стоит ли того время на фикс потенциальных проблем - решать вам =).